# Download failed if AVG anti virus installed

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, bootstrapper, antivirus

I am developing WPF application which will download and install msi using BootstrapperCore library. It works properly but after installing AVG anti-virus in my machine. Download failed in my application and have logged the failed information.

**Failed Log:**

Error 0x800700e8: Failed to wait for child to connect to pipe.

Error 0x800700e8: Failed to connect to elevated child process.

Error 0x800700e8: Failed to actually elevate.

Error 0x800700e8: Failed to elevate.

I have disabled the firewall security in AVG software and now tried to download msi file using my application and works properly. Anyone suggest me, how to restrict AVG checking for download in my application source file itself?

Comment: So, you are basically asking for a way to turn off Anti-virus programmatically? Do you think it would be a good idea, if that was possible?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest turning it off completely except in limited testing sessions. You need to tell AVG to allow your application unhindered access. How to do that exactly may depend on what version of AVG you are using.

1. Open the AVG Control Center and select AVG Firewall.
2. Go to Configuration
3. Select Applications
4. Click on "Add Application" and add your application as appropriate